# How to force a filter as landing page in the list view?

Tags: django-admin

I'd like, each time a user visit a model list in Django admin, to land in a page with a filter applied insted of no one applied.

In particular, I'd like to determine the filter applied based on a user attribute.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**

Misread your question, sorry!

To select a default filter for a user based on an user attribute, use the [**`changelist_view`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view)

---

Override the ModelAdmin queryset method.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset

example given is:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

change the filtering based on your user attribute.

Comment: This will have the effect of showing the selected filter highlighted in the admin filter?

Comment: Using queryset() will have the effect of prefiltering the objects before the user is allowed to apply filters. Using changelist_view you are able to apply a default filter based on user attribute on the entire list of objects.